# Object assignment and references question

Tags: python, class, reference

Lets say i have the following code:

```
class asd:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = "default"


def changeagain():
    xa = asd()
    xa.var = "changed"
    return xa

def change(objct:asd):
    newobjc = changeagain()
    objct = newobjc
    print(objct.var)


test = asd()

change(test)

print(test.var)
```

what i expect as output is:

```
changed
changed
```

nonetheless i get:

```
changed
default
```

What is the problem?

What i must do to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are changing the value of an object's instance variable and expecting the change to b reflected in another object. Whereas it is not possible in the case of instance variables of objects.

As per your need, I've changed certain statements in your program :

```
class asd:
    var = "default"


def changeagain():
    xa = asd()
    asd.var = "changed"
    return xa

def change(objct:asd):
    newobjc = changeagain()
    objct = newobjc
    print(objct.var)


test = asd()

change(test)

print(test.var)
```

Comment: I suppose that what i pass to `change` is a reference to `test`, now called `object` i suppose that `objct` and `test` are different pointers, and when i assign `objct` to `newobjc` the change on one doesn't get reflected on the other. If that's the case, then how i change what `test` points to with a function?

Answer (score 0):

```
class asd:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = "default"


def changeagain(asd):
    # xa = asd()
    asd.var = "changed"
    return asd

def change(asd):
    newobjc = changeagain(asd)
    objct = newobjc
    print(objct.var)


test = asd()

change(test)

print(test.var)
```

**I have commented out the object creation in the changeagain() and passed the object of the class for which you want to change the value.**

Earlier you were passing an object of the class but changing the value for a different object.

Happy coding

Comment: Yes, i know there are 2 objects and that im changing the value for just one of them, but this doesnt solve my problem, i actually want `objct` to be replaced with `newobjc` not just changing the value of `var`, that why in changeagain a new `asd` is created instead of just passing `objct` as an argument